# How can I do an HTTPS request in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

How can I do an HTTPS request in Haskell?

For example, I want to obtain a `request token` via HTTPS POST from [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#request-token)

P.S.: I am using Windows 8

Comment: If you're doing OAuth, you might want to use the [haskell oauth](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hoauth-0.3.3) package instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to learn the protocol.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks to packages like [`http-conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit), which is backed by [`tls`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tls), you can use [`simpleHttp`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-1.2.5/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:simpleHttp) for  HTTPS.

```
> import Network.HTTP.Conduit
> simpleHttp "https://github.com"
...  big ugly bytestring that can be parsed in so many ways...
```

Comment: That is one huge package... or it sure has a lot of dependencies!

Answer (score 5):

For less dependencies, use [http-client](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client) with [http-client-tls](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-tls):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Network.HTTP.Client     as H
import qualified Network.HTTP.Client.TLS as H

main :: IO ()
main = do
  httpman <- H.newManager H.tlsManagerSettings
  let req = H.setQueryString [("q", Just "r")] "https://httpbin.org/get"
  response <- H.httpLbs req httpman
  print response
```

(Those packages were factored out of http-conduit; if you have no need of conduit, sticking with http-client will decrease your dependency footprint.)